# BTYD Individual Level Estimations For All Observations

Tags: r

I am using BTYD BG NBD in R and did the individual level estimates.
For instance following the documentation in page 20 of:
[BTYD Walkthrough](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/BTYD/vignettes/BTYD-walkthrough.pdf)

Code for Data Prep:

```
system.file("data/cdnowElog.csv", package = "BTYD")%>%
dc.ReadLines(., cust.idx = 2, date.idx = 3, sales.idx = 5)%>%
dc.MergeTransactionsOnSameDate()%>%
mutate(date = parse_date_time(date, "%Y%m%d")) -> elog
end.of.cal.period <- as.Date("1997-09-30")
elog.cal <- elog[which(elog$date <= end.of.cal.period), ]
split.data <- dc.SplitUpElogForRepeatTrans(elog.cal);
birth.periods <- split.data$cust.data$birth.per
last.dates <- split.data$cust.data$last.date
clean.elog <- split.data$repeat.trans.elog;
freq.cbt <- dc.CreateFreqCBT(clean.elog);
tot.cbt <- dc.CreateFreqCBT(elog)
cal.cbt <- dc.MergeCustomers(tot.cbt, freq.cbt)
cal.cbs.dates <- data.frame(birth.periods, last.dates, end.of.cal.period)
cal.cbs <- dc.BuildCBSFromCBTAndDates(cal.cbt, cal.cbs.dates,per="week")
params <- pnbd.EstimateParameters(cal.cbs);
```

one could get estimates for a particular observation. 
Code for Individual Level Estimation:

```
cal.cbs["1516",]
# x t.x T.cal
# 26.00 30.86 31.00
x <- cal.cbs["1516", "x"]
t.x <- cal.cbs["1516", "t.x"]
T.cal <- cal.cbs["1516", "T.cal"]
bgnbd.ConditionalExpectedTransactions(params, T.star = 52,
x, t.x, T.cal)
# [1] 25.76
```

My question is, is it possible to recursively run this such that I could get a data frame containing the expectations for each row instead of hard coding a particular ID number such as "1516" in this case?

Thanks!

Comment: I'm surprised your post didn't get downvoted. Next time you ask a question, please provide more adequate information for the general viewer if they wanted to toy around with the dataset you're after. Best wishes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, it is straightforward with `dplyr`'s `mutate()`

```
cal.cbs%>%
data.frame()%>%
mutate(`Conditional Expectation` = bgnbd.ConditionalExpectedTransactions(params, T.star = 52, x, t.x, T.cal))

  x       t.x    T.cal Conditional Expectation
1 2 30.428571 38.85714               2.3224971
2 1  1.714286 38.85714               1.0646350
3 0  0.000000 38.85714               0.5607707
4 0  0.000000 38.85714               0.5607707
5 0  0.000000 38.85714               0.5607707
6 7 29.428571 38.85714               6.0231497
```